# Заполнение пустых значений массива

Tags: php

Есть

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    1367697600 => 8,
    1368043200 => 5,
    1368129600 => 16,
    1368216000 => 8
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    1368129600 => 11,
    1368216000 => 15
  )
)
```

Нужно

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    1367697600 => 8,
    1368043200 => 5,
    1368129600 => 16,
    1368216000 => 8
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    1367697600 => 0,
    1368043200 => 0,
    1368129600 => 11,
    1368216000 => 15
  )
)
```

Больший массив всегда разный, может быть первый, а может и второй

Comment: в смысле надо найти все возможные ключи и там где не хватает добавить ? зачем ?

Comment: @eicto, да.

Comment: и в чем вы видите проблему ?

Comment: @eicto, не пойму как правильно это сделать на php, возможно есть решение из предоставленных функций массивов php.

Comment: нет, подошло бы array_merge но ключи numeric и оно их переделывает. просто соберите массив всех ключей и циклом или array_map  проверяйте наличие ключа в каждом элементе массива.

Comment: @eicto, точно.